# How to make static url dynamically in mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a website where i passes  url like this:

```
<base href="http://localhost:5423/" />
```

it all working fine for local.

but now i am deploying on host and problem arises here:

On the same index.vbhtml  i have used menues like this:

```
<li><a class="home" href="Home/Index">Home</a></li>
<li class="wish"><a class="wishlist" href="Products/Index" id="wishlist-total">Products</a></li>
<li><a class="account" href="Home/Contact">Contact Us</a></li>
```

Now if i am trying with

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url
```

then its added root path everytime like  if i click on Home,it shows correct first time:

```
http://192.168.1.100/Home/Index
```

But now if i am clicking again on same link,its adding Home again:

```
http://192.168.1.100/Home/Home/Index
```

what should be the solution for this.

Regards,

Comment: Where do you have MVC ? In MVC we usually construct links via helpers - like @Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName") or via @ActionLink helper.

Comment: Thats because your missing the leading forward slash - `"/Home/Index"`. But don't hard code your url's. Use the helpers so they are always generated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Url.Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx) helper

```
<li><a class="home" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Home</a></li>
<li class="wish"><a class="wishlist" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Products")" id="wishlist-total">Products</a></li>
<li><a class="account" href="@Url.Action("Contact", "Home")">Contact Us</a></li>
```

**Edit:**

To generate absolute URLs try:

```
Url.Action("Index", "Home", null, Request.Url.Scheme)
Url.Action("Index", "Products", null, Request.Url.Scheme)
Url.Action("Contact", "Home", null, Request.Url.Scheme)
```

Comment: Art  thanks for your reply.i tried this earlier.See i am getting same issue with this.if i click on Home then url is like this:  http://192.168.1.100/Home/Index                    and after this if click on Contact  or home multiple times then Home is  added to url   everytime like this:      http://192.168.1.100/Home/Home/Index        what is the solution for this?

Comment: Hi Alex,i tried  above edit part but its still not removing the 1st part.                                    <li>  <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home",System.DBNull.Value, Request.Url.Scheme)">Home</a></li>
                       <li>  <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Products",System.DBNull.Value,Request.Url.Scheme)">Products</a></li>                                                           if i am passing null then its giving me error.please suggest here.still i am getting wrong url:          http://localhost:5423/Home/Home/Contact